# sockaddr_storage as parameter for function

Tags: c, sockets

i've got a little problem with my "simple" server while compiling.

```
gcc -lnsl -lresolv server_main.c server_function.c -o server
```

and this is the error i got, while using this command:

```
noah@noah-amd64:~/c/RvS/Abgabe3/Aufgabe6$ gcc -lnsl -lresolv 

server_main.c server_function.c -o server
In file included from server_main.c:12:0:
server_function.h:31:53: error: unknown type name ‘sockaddr_storage’
 void write_ip_port_to_buffer(unsigned char* buffer, sockaddr_storage* their_addr);
                                                 ^
In file included from server_function.c:13:0:

server_function.h:31:53: error: unknown type name ‘sockaddr_storage’

void write_ip_port_to_buffer(unsigned char* buffer, sockaddr_storage* their_addr);
                                                     ^
server_function.c:15:53: error: unknown type name ‘sockaddr_storage’
 void write_ip_port_to_buffer(unsigned char* buffer, sockaddr_storage their_addr)
```

and here are some lines of the code:

```
server_main.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include "server_function.h"

#define HASH_TABLE_SIZE 64


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

server_function.h:

```
    #ifndef INC_SERVER_FUNCTION_H
    #define INC_SERVER_FUNCTION_H



struct entry_s
{
    int key;
    int value;
    struct entry_s *next;
};

struct hashtable_s
{
    int size;
    struct entry_s *first;

};

void write_ip_port_to_buffer(unsigned char* buffer, sockaddr_storage* their_addr);

int peek_key(unsigned char* buffer);

int unpack_data_8byte(unsigned char *buffer, int *a, int *b,unsigned char *answer);

int pack_data(unsigned char* buffer,unsigned char* command_array, int a, int b);

int set_in_ht (struct hashtable_s *my_ht, int key_n, int value_n);

int get_in_ht (struct hashtable_s *my_ht,int key_n);

int del_in_ht (struct hashtable_s *my_ht,int key_n, int value_n);

#endif
```

and the last one:

```
server_function.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

#include "server_function.h"
```

i guess, i missed some include or smth like that, but i have no clue what to do now

Comment: A quick search should tell you that `sockaddr_storage` is defined in [`<sys/socket.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html). What operating systems are you running? What version?

Comment: im including `<sys/socket.h>`
`noah@noah-amd64:~/c/RvS/Abgabe3/Aufgabe6$ uname -a
Linux noah-amd64 3.13.0-70-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 16 18:34:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue:

```
void write_ip_port_to_buffer(unsigned char* buffer, sockaddr_storage* their_addr);
```

You're missing the `struct` keyword for the declaration of the `their_addr` parameter:

```
void write_ip_port_to_buffer(unsigned char* buffer, struct sockaddr_storage* their_addr);
```

Comment: thank you :) but its kinda embarrassing to miss smth like that. :D need new glasses